# How many different miniatures and how many copies of those miniatures will I need at the same time in Curse of Strahd?

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures, miniatures, curse-of-strahd

Coming up with a proper title is a bit tricky, so if people have suggestions, I'm open for them. I'm currently running Tomb of Annihilation, and having a blast. I lack a lot of the miniatures for various monsters and just use standins from my Warhammer days, but I'll be running Curse of Strahd after this, and for that, I'd like to get miniatures that fit the monsters in the campaign, and for that I need a list of all the miniatures I will need, and how many of each type are expected to be in an encounter as a maximum.

If there's no existing list, I'll most likely go through the book myself at one point, but perhaps somebody has already compiled the list once.

Basically, I'm looking for a list of all the monsters that are in the adventure (random encounter table, dungeons, any mention of them being able to appear really), and how many of those are expected to be in an encounter at the same time.

Example:

- Random encounter A has 10 zombies
- Random encounter B has 5 zombies
- Dungeon XYZ has 5 zombies in room 1
- Dungeon XYZ has 6 zombies in the room 2, which will reinforce room 1 if the trap in room 0 was triggered

This'd sum up to: 11 zombies, because 11 zombies is the number of zombies that would exist at the same time in an encounter, regardless of how many zombies exist at a time elsewhere in smaller quantities.

Answers do not need to account for players ignoring enemies and simply pulling multiple rooms at the same time, because at that point they'll die anyway, but will need to account for specific reinforcements mentioned in the book.

Specifically, I'm looking for *different* miniatures. So one encounter that has 5 zombies and one encounter that has 5 skeletons is "5 zombie miniatures and 5 skeleton miniatures", not "5 whatever miniatures" because they are separate encounters.

Unique creatures can be listed with just their name, I can find a matching miniature myself for those.

Death House is included in this question, but listing those separately for people who want to run just Death House is okay.

Comment: Do the random encounters need to be predicted for? For instance, 3d6 barovian commoners is up to 18 commoner minis

Comment: For random encounters with random amounts, listing the maximum is fine. If you're feeling generous, adding the (3d6) is great, but it's not really needed. Can never have enough peasants.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that you are set on using miniatures and will not be using Theater of the Mind in any of your battles?

Comment: That's correct, miniatures for all the fights.

Comment: Are you going to use separate miniatures for each of the npcs?

Comment: NPCs can be listed as their type. So if Bob, Greta and Ella are all commoners in a combat encounter, they are simply a 3 commoner encounter.

Comment: Are you going to start out with Death House?

Comment: I'll be starting with Death House, yeah. An answer can account for that, but does not have to. I plan to run the entire campaign eventually, so there's no need for a seperate mention for Death House, but it might help other people who plan to do the same thing and want to get their minis in batches, so adding it to an answer can be a great help to people.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Whole list of maximum of creatures in single encounter

- 1 acolyte (pg. 46)
- 1 animated armor (pg. 171)
- 1 arcanaloth (pg. 184)
- 1 archmage (pg. 39)
- 1 assasin (pg. 108)
- 1 baboon (pg. 118)
- Up to 4 bandit captains<sup>[1]</sup>, minimum of 3 (pg. 36)
- Up to 44 bandits<sup>[2]</sup> (pg. 121-122), minimum of 12 (pg. 36)
- 1 banshee (pg. 89)
- Up to 7 Barovian witches (pg. 72), minimum of 3 (pg. 72)
- 1 bat (pg. 133)
- 6 berserkers (pg. 198)
- 1 black pudding (pg. 78)
- 3 brooms of animated attack (pg. 191)
- 8 cats (pg. 114)
- 4 clay golems (pg. 170)
- 50 commoners (pg. 96)
- Up to 15 commoner's noncombatant (pg. 123), minimum of 6 (pg. 123)
- 4 cult fanatics (pg. 115)
- Up to 8 cultists (pg. 96), minimum of 2 (pg. 96)
- Up to 12 crawling claws (pg. 49), minimum of 4 (pg. 163)
- 1 death slaad (pg. 193)
- 1 deva (pg. 151)
- Up to 6 dire wolves (pg. 29), minimum of 5 (pg. 35)
- 24 draft horses (pg. 122)
- Up to 9 dretches (pg. 126)
- 6 druids (pg. 198)
- 3 flameskulls (pg. 184)
- 1 flesh golem (pg. 151)
- 10 flying swords (pg. 59)
- 8 gargoyles (pg. 55)
- 7 ghasts (pg. 192)
- 1 ghost (pg. 29), minimum of 1 (pg. 29)
- 6 ghouls (pg. 92)
- 1 giant goat (pg. 160)
- 4 giant poisonous snakes (pg. 162)
- 9 giant spiders (pg. 132)
- 3 giant wolf spiders (pg. 90)
- 1 gladiator (pg. 43)
- 9 goats (pg. 162)
- 1 gray ooze (pg. 81)
- 1 guardian portrait (pg. 70)
- Up to 24 guards (pg. 96, pg. 119), minimum of 12 (pg. 105)
- 3 hell hounds (pg. 92)
- 1 imp (pg. 115)
- 1 invisible stalker (pg. 65)
- 2 iron golems, statues of knights, you might want separate minis (pg. 82)
- 1 lich (pg. 189)
- 1 mage (pg. 109)
- 2 mastiffs (pg. 107)
- Up to 60 mongrelfolk (pg. 151), minimum of 16 (pg. 152)
- 1 mule (pg. 155)
- Up to 35 needle blights (pg. 174), minimum of 30 (pg. 174)
- 3 night hags (pg. 127)
- 1 nightmare (pg. 93)
- 2 nobles (pg. 100)
- 4 nothics (pg. 193)
- Up to 7 phantom warrior (pg. 136), minimum of 6 (pg. 138)
- 1 priest (pg. 97)
- indefinite number of ravens (pg. 142), minimum of 1 (pg. 29)
- 1 quasit (pg. 185)
- 4 red dragon wyrmlings (pg. 55)
- 5 revenants (pg. 139)
- 6 riding horses (pg. 122)
- 1 roc (pg. 159)
- 1 rug of smothering (pg. 69)
- 1 saber-toothed tiger (pg. 115)
- 7 scarecrows (pg. 162)
- Up to 6 scouts (pg. 29), minimum of 2 (pg. 100)
- 6 shadows (pg. 154)
- 1 shadow demon (pg. 79)
- 1 shield guardian (pg. 194)
- 10 skeletons (pg. 79)
- Up to 100 skeletons (eh, pg. 88 for reference)
- 1 skeleton and 1 warhorse skeleton forming one skeleton rider (you will probably need separate miniature for this one)
- 1 smoke mephit, that is actualy a dragonet (pg. 136)
- 7 specters (pg. 188)
- 3 spies (pg. 44)
- 1 stone golem (pg. 186)
- Up to 8 Strahd zombies, prepare for severed limbs (pg. 29), minimum of 6 (pg. 82)
- 1 Strahd's animated armor (pg. 69)
- 10 swarms of bats (pg. 74)
- 1 swarm of insects (pg. 51)
- Up to 7 swarms of poisonous snakes (pg. 165), minimum of 1 (pg. 165)
- Up to 8 swarms of rats (pg. 41), minimum of 4 (pg. 65)
- 4 swarms of ravens (pg. 101)
- Up to 5 thugs (pg. 49), minimum of 2 (pg. 49)
- Up to 100 toads (pg. 126)
- 1 tree blight (pg. 180)
- 24 twig blights (pg. 174)
- 6 vampire spawns (pg. 118)
- 1 veteran (pg. 43)
- 3 vine blights (pg. 198)
- 2 vrocks (pg. 157)
- 6 wereravens, both human and raven form (pg. 174)
- 3 wereravens' noncombatant (pg. 174)
- 7 werewolves, both human and raven form (pg. 171)
- Up to 15 wights (pg. 88), minimum of 7 (pg. 148)
- 1 will-o'-wisp (pg. 29), minimum of 1 (pg. 29)
- 20 wolves (pg. 35)
- 1 wraith
- 1 young blue dragon (pg. 169)
- Up to 18 zombies (pg. 29), minimum of 3 (pg. 29)

This doesn't include named NPCs from appendix D or encounters from Death House

### Death House

- 1 animated armor (pg. 214)
- 1 broom of animated attack (pg. 215)
- 2 ghasts (pg. 219)
- 2 ghosts (pg. 217)
- 4 ghouls (pg. 218)
- 1 grick (pg. 218)
- 1 mimic (pg. 219)
- 5 shadows (pg. 218)
- 1 shambling mound (pg. 220)
- 1 specter (pg. 215)
- 1 swarm of insects (pg. 217)
- indefinite number of swarms of rats (pg. 220)

---

1. > If "Mysterious Visitors" adventure hook is used and characters arrive at Area G accompanied by a travelling party
2. > Vistani camp: Alexei, 6 intoxicated Vistani in a tent, 12 bandits on a search party, 9 sober Vistani from three surrounding wagons, up to 16 sleeping Vistani from 4 surrounding wagons

Comment: You sir, are a hero. I guess it's time to start hoarding toads and skeletons.

Comment: @Theik I still advise to double check this, I can include pages with particular encounters but other can still point where I could make a mistake, the book itself isn't small.

Comment: Yeah, I expect there might be some errors, with a book this size it's nearly impossible not to mess up somewhere, but in the worst case scenario I can just alter the encounter and edit the answer afterwards for future DMs.